# Numpy ndarray displays different data structure than array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In my code

I converted a dataframe to numpy array using `.to_numpy()` and `.values` function but both return a data structure like this

```
[[1 2]
[3 4]]
```

I was expecting

```
array([[1,2], [3,4]])
```

Does anyone know what is happening ? Is the above output right ?

Comment: I think it is same ouput.

Comment: If you `print(repr(df.values))`, that is the `repr` as opposed to the `str` format, you'll get something closer to what you expect (though still with the newline).

Answer (score 0):

To prove that they are the same try

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(a)
print(list(a))
print(a.tolist())
```

and you will get

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

to show what you have and how to move between the representations.